# Getting a torrent title from metadata or torrent file

Tags: metadata, bittorrent, dht, info-hash

Is it possible to extract the torrent title from the meta data loaded from DHT or the file downloaded from some server like TPB? any api,lib  any language would do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `python` you can easily read/edit a torrent file using [bencode.py](https://gist.github.com/1126793) module

Example:

```
>>> import bencode
>>> rawdata = open('foo.torrent').read()
>>> bencode.bdecode(rawdata)
{'announce': 'http://cbbatracker.appspot.com/announce',
 'comment': 'HOTD for testing purposes',
 'created by': 'Transmission/2.04 (11151)',
 'creation date': 1292094068,
 'encoding': 'UTF-8',
 'info': {'length': 262212441,
          'name': '[SnF] Highschool of the Dead 02 [285FB2DA].mp4',
          'piece length': 131072,
          'pieces': '...lot of binary data...',
          'private': 0}}
```

Answer (score 0):

yes it's possible. Lot of open source torrent softwares use the libtorrent library.
It's available in C++ langage

[libtorrent](http://libtorrent.rakshasa.no/)

Comment: actually not really, torrent title, is website specific, I have not been able to find any fields that says it is the torrent title here

Answer (score 0):

You have to be more specific what you *actually* mean. If you meant "info.name" from the metafile, then any bencode module for any language makes that rather easy.